# Create new dataframe from multiple multi-index dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe with x amount of years which takes random seasons from previous weather data.

Code to illustrate the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=3200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(3200,1)), columns =list('A'))
df['date'] = dates
df = df[['date','A']]
```

Apply season function to the datetime index

```
def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return '2'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return '3'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return '4'
    else:
        return '1'
```

Apply the function

```
df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
```

Create a 'Year' column for indexing

```
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

Multi-index by Year and Season

```
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)
```

Create new dataframes based on season to select from

```
winters = df.query('Season == "1"')
springs = df.query('Season == "2"')
summers = df.query('Season == "3"')
autumns = df.query('Season == "4"')
```

I now want to create a new `DataFrame` which takes a random winter from the `winters`dataframe, followed by a random spring from the `springs`, followed by a random summer from `summers`and random autumn from `autumns` and does this for a specified number of years (e.g. 100) but I can't see how to do this.

EDIT:

Duplicate seasons are allowed (it should sample seasons randomly), and the first spring does not have to belong to the same year as the first winter, this doesn't matter.

**EDIT 2: Solution using all seasonal dataframes:**

```
years = df['date'].dt.year.unique()
dfs = []
for i in range(outputyears):
    dfs.append(winters.query("Year == %d"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(springs.query("Year == %d"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(summers.query("Year == %d"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(autumns.query("Year == %d"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))

rnd = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: it's not clear - are duplicates allowed? does first spring should belong to the same year as the first winter?

Comment: Apologies - duplicates are allowed (it should sample seasons randomly) , and no - the first spring should not belong to the same year as the first winter, this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably not the best way to do it, but you can do it this way:

```
years = df['date'].dt.year.unique()

dfs = []
for i in range(100):
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '1'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '2'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '3'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '4'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))

rnd = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: This does work (thanks!) for this simplified version of the problem - but it doesn't select seasons from the four separate seasonal dataframes, which is what I want to do...

Comment: Ah - I just need to change the df.query to winters.query etc. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to apply this method to a dataframe which was missing some seasons (which I need to do) and i'm hitting some errors (outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140439/sample-from-dataframe-while-respecting-seasonal-sequence) you might be able to help if you have time!