# Sample from dataframe while respecting seasonal sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm resampling from a multi-index dataframe containing seasonal data (with some years/seasons missing). I want to resample a random winter followed by a random summer followed by a random spring, but the method I'm using only samples a random season followed by a random season - even though I'm specifying which season to choose from. I can't see where I'm going wrong so here's code to illustrate:

Take a multi-index dataframe from which to resample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20100101',periods=1825)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(1825,2)), columns =list('AB'))
df['date'] = dates
df = df[['date','A', 'B']]

#season function
def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return '2'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return '3'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return '4'
    else:
        return '1'

#apply the season function to dataframe
df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)

#Year column for multi-index
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year

#season column for multi-index
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)
```

re-index so it's missing some seasons (necessary to do what I want)

```
newindex =  [(2010L, '1'), (2011L, '1'), (2011L, '3'), (2012L, '4'), (2013L, '2'), (2015L, '3')]

df = df.loc[newindex]

#recreate season and year
df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

Years variable to select range from:

```
years = df['date'].dt.year.unique()
```

Sample from the dataframe:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(100):
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '1'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '2'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '3'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Year == %d and Season == '4'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))

rnd = pd.concat(dfs)
```

This outputs a dataframe and samples seasons randomly, but even though I've selected it to choose from `Season == '1'`
`Season == '2'`
`Season == '3'`
`Season =='4'` it seems to be choosing randomly and not respecting the order of Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn (1,2,3,4). I've tried adding `replace == True` but this has no effect.

How can I adjust this so it selects a random Winter, followed by a random Spring, followed by a random Summer, then random Autumn?

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

Changing the code so it only selects season and not year helps - but it now selects more than one winter (even though I'm specifying to choose only 1)

```
dfs = []
for i in range(100):
    dfs.append(df.query("Season == '1'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Season == '2'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Season == '3'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))
    dfs.append(df.query("Season == '4'"  %np.random.choice(years, 1)))

rnd = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: The discussion below on an answer to the original question suggests that you are actually looking for a solution to a much broader problem - sampling from various dataframes, incorporating `anomalous` seasons, and the like. Take a look here on how to ask better questions and get useful advice: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.groupby()` with `TimeGrouper('Q-Nov')` to produce your seasons, `.sample()` from each season, set a new `index` for each season sample and then `.sortlevel()` accordingly:

Starting with your sample `df`, but setting `DateTimeIndex`:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20100101', periods=1825)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (1825, 2)), columns=list('AB'), index=dates) 

DatetimeIndex: 1825 entries, 2010-01-01 to 2014-12-30
Freq: D
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    1825 non-null int64
B    1825 non-null int64
```

This allows for `groupby()` with `TimeGrouper()`, shifting quarter end to November (and assigning values in December at the end of the series to the first season again). Assigns the `max()` of `.month` for each group, translated via `season_dict` back to the original `df` using `.transform()`:

```
season_dict = {2: 1, 5: 2, 8: 3, 11: 4}
df['season'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('Q-Nov')).A.transform(lambda x: season_dict.get(x.index.month.max(), 1))
```

Create `year` column and set `season` and `year` to `index`:

```
df['year'] = df.index.to_series().dt.year.astype(int)
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['year', 'season'])
```

Get unique `(year, season)` combinations from the `index`:

```
sample_seasons = df.reset_index().loc[:, ['year', 'season']].drop_duplicates()
```

Sample from the result, using `.reset_index()` to ensure you can sort after:

```
sample_seasons = sample_seasons.groupby('season').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5).reset_index(drop=True))
sample_seasons = sample_seasons.reset_index(0, drop=True).sort_index()
```

Convert into format so that you can select from `MultiIndex` later to pull entire `season`:

```
sample_seasons = list(sample_seasons.values)
sample_seasons = [tuple(s) for s in sample_seasons]

[(2011, 1), (2013, 2), (2011, 3), (2014, 4), (2014, 1), (2010, 2), (2010, 3), (2012, 4)]

sample = df.loc[sample_seasons]
```

which yields:

```
                 index   A   B
year season                   
2011 1      2011-01-01  33  64
     1      2011-01-02  91  66
     1      2011-01-03  37  47
     1      2011-01-04   1  87
     1      2011-01-05  68  47
     1      2011-01-06  92  60
     1      2011-01-07  81   7
     1      2011-01-08  78  13
     1      2011-01-09  31  67
     1      2011-01-10  24  50
     1      2011-01-11  71  55
     1      2011-01-12  56  37
     1      2011-01-13  25  87
     1      2011-01-14  24  55
     1      2011-01-15  29  97
     1      2011-01-16  70  94
     1      2011-01-17  18  37
     1      2011-01-18  95  30
     1      2011-01-19  58  87
     1      2011-01-20  75  96
     1      2011-01-21  52  63
     1      2011-01-22  60  75
     1      2011-01-23  39  58
     1      2011-01-24  86  24
     1      2011-01-25  61  21
     1      2011-01-26  19  24
     1      2011-01-27   5  71
     1      2011-01-28  72  81
     1      2011-01-29   0  45
     1      2011-01-30  80  48
...                ...  ..  ..
2012 4      2012-11-01  90  44
     4      2012-11-02  43  53
     4      2012-11-03   3  49
     4      2012-11-04  38   7
     4      2012-11-05  64  44
     4      2012-11-06  82  44
     4      2012-11-07  38  75
     4      2012-11-08   7  96
     4      2012-11-09  52   9
     4      2012-11-10  32  64
     4      2012-11-11  30  38
     4      2012-11-12  91  70
     4      2012-11-13  63  18
     4      2012-11-14  77  29
     4      2012-11-15  58  51
     4      2012-11-16  90  17
     4      2012-11-17  87  85
     4      2012-11-18  64  79
     4      2012-11-19  10  61
     4      2012-11-20  76  52
     4      2012-11-21   9  40
     4      2012-11-22  15  28
     4      2012-11-23  14  33
     4      2012-11-24  24  74
     4      2012-11-25  38  43
     4      2012-11-26  27  87
     4      2012-11-27   6  30
     4      2012-11-28  91   3
     4      2012-11-29  32  64
     4      2012-11-30   0  28
```

Comment: Thank you for this - and sorry for not being clearer - I don't want to randomly sample days from each season, I want to keep each season the same (e.g. from 01-12-2011 to the 28-02-2012 is winter, and should be kept as winter). So the new dataframe takes one random winter from the dataframe, followed by a random spring, summer and autumn - but all of these seasons are still the complete observations, not samples of the observations.

Comment: thanks again - but when I do this it now selects all the winters, followed by all the springs, all the summers and all the autumns. I'm looking for a sequence with random winter, random spring, random summer, random autumn (1 complete year) and so on for x number of years. Your answer helps, but it's doing something very similar to what I had originally. This is a simplified version of the code I'm working on, which selects from multiple multi-index dataframes with missing seasons, so I need it to choose a random spring followed by random summer etc. I hope this makes sense...

Comment: The output shows the random sample `[(2011, 1), (2013, 2), (2011, 3), (2014, 4), (2014, 1), (2010, 2), (2010, 3), (2012, 4)]`, which seem to be what you are looking for. Are you saying you are running the same code but it's producing a different result? I wasn't aware that the answer is just a simplification of your work as it uses `MultiIindex` and `.groupby()`, but perhaps you can explain.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-ran it and it is respecting the seasonal sequence. In reality I have a number of dataframes with different seasons in them, some have anomalously warm seasons, cold seasons, wet seasons, and dry seasons. These dataframes are also missing seasons and may be missing entire years. Therefore I need to be able to deterministically select a random cold winter, followed by a random wet spring, followed by a random hot summer (or any possible permutations of these options). Your answer helps for creating dataframes, but doesn't allow for the generation of a new dataframe

Comment: Looks like this is info worth adding to the question, where you ask for 'sampling from dataframe requesting sequence'. However, you can of course create a new `DataFrame` from your various `MultiIndex` selections (I am in fact creating a new frame `sample` above), and you could also do this from various `DataFrame` sources. But you would need to address mapping `anomalous` seasons to fit a common naming sampling scheme. In any case, IMHO the best approach would be to use randomly sampled `tuples` to grab the necessary data. Enough time spent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111660/discussion-between-pad-and-stefan-jansen).